# Changing Battery Parameters with Resistor

Tags: batteries, pcb, resistors

I'm fairly new to Electrical Engineering but I have [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B7RT7CF4) board that I'm using the Teyleten Robot IP2368 and so the way my batteries are setup currently is there are 3 in series and 4 in parallel, they are then connected to a BMS board and the BMS board is connected to this board, so I have to change the values as the default for this board is 4s and I saw that to change the values you use resistors, I was wondering if to change the value I have to remove what's currently at that point or if I add a resistor just right there will it be fine?

Thank you and please bear with me as I figure out and try to navigate this very confusing space!

Answer (score 0):

I will say without a schematic to check the design no. Mistakes can cause the lithium batteries to fail in a spectacular fashion. I did not see any information in you link to make me think it would be ok to change resistors adjust its parameters.

From the images it does not matter if you parallel them or place them in series, the end value is what they want. Normally the images are just advertisement so I ignore them as I did in your case.

Comment: If you look through the images, it explains what resistor will control what parameters and the value they should be, its also on the data sheet (though that is only in mandarin)